# SQL: converting distinct column data in duplicate rows into columns in MS Access

Tags: sql, csv, ms-access, data-cleaning

So I'm working with data from csv-files that are a bit chaotic. Lot's of duplicate rows with the last two values constituting what should be a separate header and data in that column, like this:

| ID | Name | Date | field4 | field5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 21-03-23 | Flavour | Strawberry |
| 1 | John | 21-03-23 | Location | Kitchen |
| 2 | Jane | 21-04-18 | Flavour | Lime |
| 2 | Jane | 21-04-18 | Location | Basement |

I've cleaned data in Access up until now with just a INSTER INTO statement, since all duplicate rows with the same primary key will be overlooked. A query like this:

```
INSERT INTO b (ID, Name, Date, field4, field5)
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.Date, a.field4, a.field5
FROM a;
```

,which returns something like this:

| ID | Name | Date | field4 | field5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 21-03-23 | Flavour | Strawberry |
| 2 | Jane | 21-04-18 | Flavour | Lime |

However, now I would need all the different values in field4 and field5 to be transformed into new columns, so the data won't be lost. Like this:

| ID | Name | Date | Flavour | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 21-03-23 | Strawberry | Kitchen |
| 2 | Jane | 21-04-18 | Lime | Basement |

How can this be done in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, name, date,
       max(iif(field4 = "Flavour", field5, null)) as flavour,
       max(iif(field4 = "Location", field5, null)) as Location
from t
group by id, name, date;
```

This assumes that you know the columns that you want in the result set.  If not, you would need to generate the query string in some way to do a more dynamic query.

Comment: It's really strange, because when I try this with an example table of three duplicate rows it works, but when I do it with the one of the tables I handle att work, with thirteen duplicate rows per entry, it all breaks down and starts to skip data in two of the columns.

Comment: @NimaDT . . . It sounds like something like `Name` has values that look the same but are not.

Comment: Yes, one column has a nummerical departement code, and then two columns concatenates that code with an underscore and the name of a manager. Is there a workaround? I've tried to skip the column with the departement code in (no "max(iif())")...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self-join:

```
SELECT D.ID, D.[Name], D.[Date], D.Field5 AS Flavour, D1.Field5 AS Location
FROM tblData AS D1 INNER JOIN tblData AS D 
    ON D1.[Date] = D.[Date] 
    AND D1.[Name] = D.[Name] 
    AND D1.ID = D.ID
WHERE 
    D.Field4="Flavour" 
    AND D1.Field4="Location";
```

Note that `Name` and `Date` are reserved words in Access, so I've 2rapped them in square brackets - you should rename the fields now before you get too far into the design of the database.

Regards,